# Angular: only get return value [object Object]

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an Angular Frontend with Spring-Boot Backend integration. **For testing purposes** i want to get database entries in the Console.log. It works that I get the specific entries, but the Output is only [object Object] instead of the real database-entry.

This are my service-methods (just a part), where I got a Get-Method for getting all my entries and jsut for a specific entry (which is marked with an ID):

```
getVorgaenge(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getDataURL);
  }

  getVorgaengeID(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.getDataURL}/${id}`);
  }
```

My component.ts looks like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private vorgangService : VorgangService) { }

  vorgaenge: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllVorgaenge();
  }


  getAllVorgaenge() {
    this.vorgangService.getVorgaenge().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.vorgaenge = data;
        console.log("Alle Einträge:" + this.vorgaenge);

        data = Math.max.apply(0, this.vorgaenge.map(function(v) {return v.id}));
        console.log("Höchster Eintrag: " + data);

        this.vorgangService.getVorgaengeID(data).subscribe(newdata => {
          this.vorgaenge = newdata;
        })
        console.log("Eintrag mit höchster ID: " + this.vorgangService.getVorgaengeID(data));  

      })
  }
```

I want to get the last entry of the database (i've done this with the Math.max-function. It works fine, but the output in the console is only "Eintrag mit höchster ID: [object Object]"

I need the exact entry of the last entry (of which i get the ID with Math.max). It should be working, but the output needs to be converted to the real json-database-entry.

Comment: [object Object] because this.vorgangService.getVorgaengeID(data) return observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating an object with string so it gives you [Object object] as a string representation.

You should either log it with comma or use JSON.stringify.

```
var data = { a: "1", b: "2" };

console.log("My data is " + data); // Wrong
console.log("My data is ", data); // Right
console.log("My data is " + JSON.stringify(data)); // Also not bad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.table if your data is in proper JSON format.
ex:

```
console.table(data);
```